# std::reference_wrapper unwrap the wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

#### Introduction.

In C++ we cannot create containers of references:

```
std::vector<int&> vri;
```

> ```
> In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int&>’:
> required from ‘class std::allocator<int&>’
> required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<int&, std::allocator<int&> >’
> required from ‘class std::vector<int&>’
> required from here
> error: forming pointer to reference type ‘int&’
>        typedef _Tp*       pointer;
>                           ^~~~~~~
> ```

The internal implementation requires to create a pointer to the contained type, that leads to the *pointer to reference* forbidden type.

Luckily, [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) exists:

```
int x{1}, y{2}, z{3};
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vr{x, y, z};
for (auto &v : vr)
    ++v;
std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n';
```

Code above shows `2 3 4`.

#### Problem.

I'm working on a C++ filter utility, as example the filter `where` receives a container and returns `std::reference_wrapper` to the contained objects that meets the criteria:

```
template <typename container_t> auto range(const container_t &container)
{ return std::tuple{std::begin(container), std::end(container)}; };

template <typename container_t, typename predicate_t>
auto where(const container_t &container, predicate_t predicate)
{
    auto [b, e] = range(container);
    using type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*b)>;
    using reference = std::reference_wrapper<type>;

    std::vector<reference> result{};

    std::copy_if(b, e, std::back_inserter(result), predicate);

    return result;
}
```

Code below shows `2 3 6 7`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (auto &x : where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }))
        std::cout << x << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

But I have a problem chaining filters:

```
for (const auto &x :
    where(where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }), [](auto n){ return n & 0b1; })) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

> ```
> no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const std::reference_wrapper<const std::reference_wrapper<const int> >’)
>    std::cout << x << ' ';
>    ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
> ```

Inner `where` returns `std::vector<std::refernce_wrapper<int>>`, so the outer one will use `std::vector<std::refernce_wrapper<const std::refernce_wrapper<const int>>>`.

#### What have I tried?.

In order to solve the problem, I've tried to create a template that unwraps `std::reference_wrapper<T>`:

```
template <typename type_t>
struct unwrap
{
    using type = type_t;
};

template <typename type_t>
struct unwrap<std::reference_wrapper<type_t>>
{
    using type = type_t;
};

template <typename type_t>
using unwrap_t = typename unwrap<type_t>::type;
```

So far, it looks like it's working:

```
int main()
{
    using ri = std::reference_wrapper<int>;
    using rf = std::reference_wrapper<float>;
    using rri = std::reference_wrapper<ri>;
    using rrri = std::reference_wrapper<rri>;

    std::cout
        << typeid(int).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<int>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(float).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<float>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(ri).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<ri>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(rf).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<rf>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(rri).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<rri>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(rrri).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<rrri>).name();

    return 0;
}
```

It yields the propper [mangled names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling):

> ```
>   i   i
>   f   f
>   St17reference_wrapperIiE    i
>   St17reference_wrapperIfE    f
>   St17reference_wrapperIS_IiEE    St17reference_wrapperIiE
>   St17reference_wrapperIS_IS_IiEEE    St17reference_wrapperIS_IiEE
> ```

Integer and floating point (`int`, `float`) remains the same, integer and floating point wrappers get unwrapped and nested wrappers unwrap one level.

But it doesn't work inside `where`:

```
template <typename container_t, typename predicate_t>
auto where(const container_t &container, predicate_t predicate)
{
    auto [b, e] = range(container);
    using type = unwrap_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*b)>>;
    //           ^^^^^^^^ <--- Unwraps iterator's inner type
    using reference = std::reference_wrapper<type>;

    std::vector<reference> result{};

    std::copy_if(b, e, std::back_inserter(result), predicate);

    // Debug
    std::cout
        << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"
        << '\t' << "decltype(*b) = " << typeid(decltype(*b)).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "unwrap *b = " << typeid(unwrap_t<decltype(*b)>).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "type = " << typeid(type).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "reference = " << typeid(reference).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "unwrap type = " << typeid(unwrap_t<type>).name() << '\n';

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (const auto &x :
        where(where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }), [](auto n){ return n & 0b1; })) {
        std::cout << &x << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Debug logs into `where` shows that the unwrapper worked on the first call (it did nothing to the type), but not on the second call:

> ```
>   auto where(const container_t&, predicate_t) [with container_t = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >; predicate_t = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]
>       decltype(*b) = i
>       unwrap *b = i
>       type = i
>       reference = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       unwrap type = i
>   auto where(const container_t&, predicate_t) [with container_t = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const int> > >; predicate_t = main()::<lambda(auto:2)>]
>       decltype(*b) = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       unwrap *b = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       type = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       reference = St17reference_wrapperIKS_IKiEE
>       unwrap type = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
> ```

On the inner call, input container is `std::vector<int>`, so the iterator inner type (`decltype(*b)`), the unwrapping (`unwrap_t<decltype(*b)>`), tye type (`type`) and the unwrapped type (`unwrap_t<type>`) are `int`, only `reference` is `std::reference_wrapper`.

On the outer call, input container is `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>>` and all tye types (except `reference`) are `std::reference_wrapper<const int>`, as if the unwrapper ignored the input type.

#### Question.

What am I doing wrong on my unwrapper? I think the issue might be related to `const` propagation.

Code available on <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRdb9MwFH1ufsVVkdqEeagb302WFwQSLwOh8oC2yXIdN7NInci56aiq/nWK42SJ6crGEC@Rc@499@tcmxfFccr5bvdEKp5ViYBI5iVqwZax12MrwTHXLoJVkQkXWFSKo8wVy1yUZWmuJV7/Fg3XhaComcQy9jwUyyJj2OKKLQXwXCGTSmiKMbAKc9BMpcIHcE0w6n6MIYANaIGVVlBiMp3aAjf2OBepVH7nHJDGQ6jEAbchbMPHFGPwEv9Qz/8p5lA1zexiz2hUcYRK3WhWeBtvUJVSpdYMZ61X6D0mSGTr0GIhtFBc0BorhG7ViuN/TdJwmhxmSA3PerR5W0czJXMIH1oI0vMLLRLJjWedxipzc22Kv1cZ4rL6c1B3Z0NczAmIK1Nmp3KrSXjbfqUSobO1OdJ2Eu3klvlKUJucYpQIntVm/@k8iMO90d1OI3KZ/egx2ssR9xE6rz7vIcUMwRtYe3N3o84tNiHKKsPNtnPhebGmcuHXrbf7OGf8O5WqFBqF9htG4AwvcMgVeoNBFAGln7@8n82@0Q9fz9/NPn46pxQMPLxUw8ZhfIlji7jDMX0Ma7D@l4nvmoJntc5@AJarxntR7grhBtqzPhDrQIC/YLliuNQO3@fXU2sfhmam5vp4nlQIS7Nlvl1DRzVYbSYETgicEnhO4AWBlwReEXhN4A2Bt1bBhXFrV94u8OgHTNuL0HxXBC6ufGtTQfcuKRjBZH4yMS9NcJ9DbQ9M253WdSsmx92GJqaX3e4nX2QsLXfHhnDGj45O2S8)</kbd>.

Comment: Can you reorganize all the bunches of code snippets in your question into a single code sample that anyone can easily cut/paste, attempt to compile, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: After piecing together the various code snippets, the shown code compiles without issues by gcc 9.2. Either this is a bug in your compiler, or the shown code is not the real code that's causing the compilation error. I won't waste any more time on this until I see a [mre].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You can copy past the code in the online link, if you have read until the end. BTW, there is no compilation error. You just need to take 5 seconds and read the code snippet.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you have a single working code snippet in the last link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is, that `*b` returns a const value (since the container is passed by const reference). Your `unwrap` only works on non-const, non-volatile `reference_wrapper`. I would go as follows at this problem:

```cpp
#include <functional>

namespace detail{
template <typename type_t, class  orig_t>
struct unwrap_impl
{
    using type = orig_t;
};

template <typename type_t, class V>
struct unwrap_impl<std::reference_wrapper<type_t>,V>
{
    using type = type_t;
};
}

template<class T>
struct unwrap {
  using type = typename detail::unwrap_impl<std::decay_t<T>, T>::type;
};

template <typename type_t>
using unwrap_t = typename unwrap<type_t>::type;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, unwrap_t<const int &>>);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, unwrap_t<std::reference_wrapper<const int &>>>);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, unwrap_t<const std::reference_wrapper<const int &>&>>);
}
```

This should return the original type for anything not a `reference_wrapper` and the inner type for cv-qualified `reference_wrapper`s and references thereto.

---

**Explanation**: I will call the original `unwrap` from OP `UNWRAP` in the following to differentiate with my version. We want to invoke the reference_wrapper specification of `UNWRAP` whenever `std::decay_t<T>` is a `std::reference_wrapper`. Now this could be simply accomplished if we always invoke `UNWRAP` with `std::decay_t<T>` instead of `T`.

The problem with this is, that if `T` is not a reference_wrapper, this will remove all qualifications, i.e. `UNWRAP<std::decay_t<const int>>` is `int` when we would want it to be `const int`.

To get around this we define us `template<class type_t, class orig_t> struct unwrap_impl`. We want to always pass this the decayed type for the first argument and the original type (before decaying) as the second argument. Then, we can pass for the general case `orig_t` as the result type (as done by `using type = orig_t`).

For the specification, we define `template<class type_t, class V> struct unwrap_impl<std::reference_wrapper<type_t>, V>`. This will apply whenever `type_t` is a reference_wrapper, i.e. when the orignal type is some qualification of a reference_wrapper. We don't care about the second argument (which will be the original type), so we just ignore it. Then we take the inner type of the reference_wrapper as type (`using type = type_t;`).

Then we call `unwrap_impl` by defining basically `template<class type_t> unwrap = detail::unwrap_impl<std::decay_t<type_t>, type_t>;` (this is pseudocode but I think this makes it more clear.

Some examples:

```cpp
unwrap<int> -> unwrap_impl<int, int> -> int
unwrap<const int> -> unwrap_impl<int, const int> -> const int
unwrap<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> -> unwrap_impl<std::reference_wrapper<const int>, std::reference_wrapper<const int>> -> const int
unwrap<const std::reference_wrapper<const int>> -> unwrap_impl<const std::reference_wrapper<const int>, const std::reference_wrapper<const int>> -> const int
```

(Again more pseudocode, but I hope its clear)

Edit: fixed some bugs.

Edit2: Seems to work: [link](https://tio.run/##rVRdb9MwFH1ufsXVkLaEeajja5BmeUFM4mUgVJDQNlmu42YWqRM5TkdV9a9Tbpw0MW1ZQaIPVXLvOed@hxfFWcr5ev1EKp5ViYBI5qXRgs1ir7fNBTe5di2mKjLhGqaV4kbmimWulWVprqW5/03NLApBjWbSlLGn2EyUBeMCEmGYzJaeEbMiY6YF1n5oGAR4xsoSACVTauCytcceZlxxA5V60KygEvne0gP8VaVUqYUhuqGNvNXIOxzk6z7VqDRJGGoxFVooLmjtKIRuK4oJkvbEbbw27qqPHDVxxltxoBbYodsEmwaF4U5CieBsQU00jgnqhWHNOFBm7DUxWi3jxmlsm6I2cnvFeK4wJyU0AoFVJgfNVCp8bIHjguPuBR0BLEELU2kFNnu7Skv7OBGpVH4HDkiDECpxjKsRYGn/kAzaS/OHfP5PMgeyIX1vCy0SyRFZj8Dm@HCPy/RojsRl9c8B7trAStxMCIg7HGFXb5vdyBtsxpwInS3wkbZb1W7yLJ8LaoPj/uAeZbXbfzoJ4o7bEjabErnM/hRMtBUj7hU6VB933wUhwRtYf/O9iTpYjBJllZnlqoPwvFhQOfXr0tvJTBj/TqUqhTZC@w0jcJoXOOTKeINBFAGlnz6/H4@/0asv1@/GHz5eUwpoPrpVRw3g5NacWIvbHKzjqDbW7zLxXVfwrJ6zH4DlqpMtld1BuEJb3gNaewT@guUOw6V29m1@3bX2RJqe2s@YVAZmuGW@XUNnajBfDgmcE3hO4AWBlwReEXhN4ILAGwJv7QSnCGtX3i7w8Q8I20No/ucEbu5861NBd6EKjmE4OR/izQWPAWp/gGV3s65LwRi7BQ2xlvX6J59mLC3XZ0i45Ken5xe/AA)

Comment: Can you please explain the `unwrap_impl` a bit? I found it hard to follow. :(

Comment: Sure thing! I added an explanation, I hope it makes it clear. Let me know, if you want to know more.

Comment: The default value `orig_t = type_t` of template parameter is not necessary, right?

Comment: Yes, I first thought this would enable us to get rid of the second template parameter in the specification, but that did not work out. I will remove it.